# Documentation for standalone REST WS

Tags: rest, apache-spark

Using Spark 1.3.1, when a master node is started with `./sbin/start-master.sh`, a RESTful webservice is started on that machine (for me port 6066). Is there any documentation on how to interact with that service?

I found [this code](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest), but I was not able to find the corresponding Scaladoc let alone some sort of guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5388), contains the Design Doc that motived this feature.

> The goal is to create a new submission gateway that is stable across Spark versions

Additionally,

> It is also not a goal to expose the new gateway as a general mechanism
>   for users of Spark to submit their applications. The new gateway will
>   be used strictly internally between Spark submit and the standalone
>   Master.

Comment: Right. It seems that this is meant for internal use only right now, which is probably why it isn't documented.